# 404 error with XMLHttpRequest on document that exists

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

Im using XMLHttpRequest to save something into a database when the user clicks a button. This seems to work when working on localhost, but after I launched the site only a 404-error occurs.

Firefox console says:

```
POST http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/minmeme/save.php [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 999ms]
```

But when I copy that URL and open it manually, the file clearly exists.

Javascript code is saved in `script.js` and placed in the same folder as `save.php`:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'/wp-content/themes/minmeme/save.php',false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(imgurl);
```

Comment: "placed in same folder as `save.php`" => on `ajax.open` you should only have to use `save.php` instead of the full `/wp-content/themes/minmeme/save.php`. (I think :)).

Comment: Thats what I also thought, but then the URL is `http://mydomain.com/save.php` for some reason. I tried to put the save.php-file at root also, but then the browser gives 404 error aswell (I think Wordpress screws it up then).

Comment: What happens if you access the URL through the browser? Why are you setting this strange request header? Does it work without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the WordPress permalink structure that screwed this up. By using custom permalinks (%postname%) I could not access any .php-file outside of Wordpress directly.

Setting permalinks to standard, now the server finds the file. Error now changed to 403.1 though...